# Import same html with two Html.Partial have same id

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am importing one .cshtml file twice in another cshtml. I setting up different id for every imported partial view but when I tried get id clicked element, it returned same id.

This is part of root cshtml where I calling partial view:

```
<div class="row g-mt-20">
    <div class="col-lg-5 text-lg-center">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Partial("ColorPicker", "bgColorPicker")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div id="colorPreview" class="g-px-5 g-py-5" style="background-color:@Model.ApplicationUser.EventBackgroundColorHex;color:@Model.ApplicationUser.EventForegroundColorHex">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and type setting industry.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 text-lg-center">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Partial("ColorPicker", "frColorPicker")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is that partial view:

```
@model string

<img style='margin-right:2px;' src='~/images/img_colormap.gif' usemap='#colormap' alt='colormap' /> 

@if(Model == "bgColorPicker") {
    <map id='bgColorPicker' name='colormap'>
    @await Html.PartialAsync("ColorAreas")
    </map>
} else if (Model == "frColorPicker") {
    <map id='frColorPicker' name='colormap'>
    @await Html.PartialAsync("ColorAreas")
    </map>
} else {
    <map id='colormap' name='colormap'>
    @await Html.PartialAsync("ColorAreas")
    </map>
}
```

Here is one of many elements with onclick event from ColorAreas partial view:

```
<area style='cursor:pointer' shape='poly' coords='180,15,189,19,189,30,180,34,171,30,171,19' onclick='clickColor("#333399", event)' alt='#333399' />
```

Here is javascript where I calling parentElement:

```
function clickColor(hex, e) {
    var colorPreview = document.getElementById("colorPreview");
    var colorPicker = e.target.parentElement.id;
    console.log(colorPicker);
}
```

console.log(colorPicker) every time returned "bgColorPicker".

And here is generated html from browser

```
...
<map id="bgColorPicker" name="colormap">...</map>
...
<map id="frColorPicker" name="colormap">...</map>
...
```

Screen from chrome browser:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the demo to reproduce the issue . After continuous testing, I finally found the problem exists in the map between the image and area. Since the `map-name` between `bgColorPicker` and `frColorPicker` are all `colormap` ,the default click is the area in `bgColorPicker` section when you click on an area in a different section.

So you could change your ColorPicker partial view like below :  **Different sections have different map-names of image**

```
@model string
@if (Model == "bgColorPicker")
{
  <img style='margin-right:2px;' src='~/images/img_colormap.gif' usemap='#bgcolormap' alt='colormap' />

   <map id='bgColorPicker' name='bgcolormap'>
      @await Html.PartialAsync("ColorAreas")
   </map>
}

else if (Model == "frColorPicker")
{
   <img style='margin-right:2px;' src='~/images/img_colormap.gif' usemap='#frcolormap' alt='colormap' />

   <map id='frColorPicker' name='frcolormap'>
      @await Html.PartialAsync("ColorAreas")
   </map>
}

else
{
   <img style='margin-right:2px;' src='~/images/img_colormap.gif' usemap='#colormap' alt='colormap' />

   <map id='colormap' name='colormap'>
      @await Html.PartialAsync("ColorAreas")
   </map>
}
```